# Path of least resistance vs. short circuit

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons

Some sources on the web claim that "electricity follows the path of least resistance" is not true, e.g. [this physics SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/electricity-takes-the-path-of-least-resistance). However, in every explanation of "short circuits", the author says that current flows through the short because it's following the path of least resistance. How do I reconcile these two facts?

Comment: Which ***author*** says that? You can think of the short as an extremely low resistance, in which case *majority* of the current will flow through the short. You will get some current through the resistance too, but it will be quite negligible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more like "Electricity *tries* to follow the path of least resistance". The sentence is a non-rigorous intuitive tool that helps one quickly make sense of current paths. It's not a physical law.

This comes from the behavior of resistors  in parallel --this is where current has a "choice" of which direction to take. The potential difference across a resistor is equal to the current into its resistance ($V=IR$, usually called Ohm's law) in appropriate units.

What happens when you have two resistors in parallel is that the p.d. across them must be the same. Which means that $I_1R_1=I_2R_2$. So, more current flows through the resistor with less resistance and vice versa. Current still flows through the greater resistance.

So *most* current flows through the path of least resistance. In the case of a short circuit, one of the Rs is (nearly) zero, and thus (almost) all the current flows through it.

Comment: Many authors write that the potential difference across the ends of a short circuit is zero. I cannot understand how charge flows between two points when the potential difference between them is zero. Can charge flow between two points having 0 potential difference?For short circuits is the resistance taken to be infinitesimally small instead of zero so that the potential difference comes out to be non-zero as opposed to the case when zero is taken in which the potential difference comes out to be zero?

Comment: @MrAP it becomes zero in steady state. If you short-circuit something with a fixed potential difference (a battery), the potential difference is not zero.

Answer (score 4):

The statement *electricity flows through the path of least resistance* means that *electricity flows **more** into the path with less resistance*, because it is proportional to the inverse of resistance, obeying:

[image]

$$I_1=I\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$
$$I_2=I\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}$$

From these relations you can find out that in two cases all of the current flows through the 1st resistor:

- $R_1=0$
- $R_2\gg R_1$ $($mathematically $R_2\to\infty$ $)$

The important fact is that what matters here is the ratio of the resistances:
$$I_1=I\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\to I_1=I\frac{1}{\frac{R_1}{R_2}+1}$$

If you plot $I_1\over I$ from the above relation (w.r.t $\frac{R_1}{R_2}$ ) you can see this better:

[image]

This is the meaning of the quoted statement.

Comment: How did you get the I_1 and I_2 equations?

Comment: @Zach: Stuff from basic electrodynamics. Try applying the resistance adding equation.