# Why does current always go to the resistance which is lower?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Why does current chose the easy way? Is there a proper mathematical 
formula about why current tends to go over a resistance which is smaller?

Comment: We generally don't do homework here. So start from the beginning, why would current go through the most resistance?

Comment: First draw a circuit with options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electricity takes the path of least resistance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5670/)

Answer (score 2):

Current doesn't always go through a resistance which is lower. If you have two ohmic resistors in parallel, both of them will have current through them. Yes, there will be a larger current through the more conductive resistor (lower resistance), but there is current in the less conductive resistor (more resistance), too. So you can't say that current **always** goes through the lower resistance.

Ohm's Law, which is typically used to describe this situation does not tell us **why** this happens. It only tells us that it will. It is a phenomenological/experimental relationship. It merely tells us a relationship between voltage and current through an ohmic circuit element.

To answer **why** one would have to understand some condensed matter physics.

Comment: You can use KVL to prove that two resistors in parallel must both see the same voltage...

Answer (score 0):

From Ohm's law
$$
j = \sigma E
$$
you directly see that to say "current always chose to go to lower resistance" is not accurate. $j$, which is more precise to describe currents, exists as long as there is an electric field around.

So it's better to say currents *tend* to go where the resistance is lower. In fact, for a parallel circuit, we have a distribution of current 
$$
i_j = \frac{G_j}{\sum\limits_i G_i}i_{total}
$$
so the current of jth branch is proportional to its $R^{-1}$, which confirms the trend of currents we were considering about.

Comment: What about when Ohm's law is not valid?